# How to print multiple line in console in javascript?

Tags: java, console

I was trying to print multiple line (given below) in console, buy i could not print it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    <h1>Hello '{{name}}'</h1>enter code here

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in console ? where i can't see any `console.log`s

Comment: firstly, `java !== javascript` secondly, if you want to send something to console, then you have to use one of console.log console.info console.warn etc methods to do so - you don't even have any javsacript in the the code you posted, so perhaps you need a refresher course in javascript first

Comment: i was trying to print those line of codes in java console, i used few \ for special characters and worked. Thanks

Comment: Is this a java or a javascript question? Could you state exactly what languages you're using for what parts in your question?

Comment: i am learning java and trying to print those html code as a string,

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
public class MultipleStringPrint {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "<!DOCTYPE html> \n <html lang=\"en-US\"> \n "
            + "\"<script src=\"http:\\/\\/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js\"><\\/script> \n    "
            + "<body> \n <div ng-app=\"\">\n "
            + "<p>Name : <input type=\"text\" ng-model=\"name\"></p>\n \t "
            + "<h1>Hello '{{name}}'</h1>\n "
            + "\t <\\/div>\n    "
            + "<\\/body>\n  "
            + "<\\/html>\n";

    System.out.println(str);
}
|
```